# hide UITabBarController's tab bar when pushing UIViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I have a tab bar application.
Here's launching code

```
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];



    self.tabBarController=[[UITabBarController alloc] init];


    StartViewController *startViewController=[[StartViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"StartViewController" bundle:nil];
    NavRootViewController *navRootViewController=[[NavRootViewController alloc] initWithNavControllerWithSubViewController:startViewController];

    HelpViewController *helpViewController=[[HelpViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HelpViewController" bundle:nil];

    SettingsViewController *settingsViewController=[[SettingsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SettingsViewController" bundle:nil];

    AboutUsViewController *aboutUsViewController=[[AboutUsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AboutUsViewController" bundle:nil];

    [self.tabBarController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: navRootViewController, helpViewController, settingsViewController, aboutUsViewController, nil]];



    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.window.rootViewController=self.tabBarController;
```

Application launched with 4 tab bar tabs.
This action is called after  user presses start button in the first tab's navigation controller's root view controller

```
-(IBAction)startPressed:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"startPressed: called");


    RootViewController *vController=[[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RootViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vController animated:YES];

}
```

This works fine but I need to hide tab bar for my `RootViewController`
property `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` does not work.
Help me please, how can it be done?

Comment: Present your root view as a modalviewcontroller.That will hide the tabBar below it.

Comment: where have you assigned hidesBottomBarWhenPushed?

Comment: @iPhoneDeveloper If I call `[self presentModalViewController:vController animated:YES]` tab bar remains visible. Whats the problem. I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: @iPhoneDeveloper I solved this problem. Please make a separate answer with your comment.

Comment: Yea you have to add the modalview on window not on the viewcontroller of tabBar.m giving the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yea you have to add the modalview on window not on the viewcontroller of tabBar.
 Try something like.. make an object of AppDelegate like: 
`AppDelegate *appDelegate=[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];` 
then in next line add

```
[appDelegate.window.rootviewcontroller.view presentModalViewController:vController animated:YES];
```

or add your code `[self presentModalViewController:vController animated:YES]` in the viewDidAppear of the firstviewcontroller of tabBar.

What did you do to solve the problem??I would like to know that also.

Answer (score 6):

I hope this helps you:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear: (BOOL)animated 
{ 
    self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the main view to show the tab bar, you shouldn't be pushing it onto the navigation controller. Doing this causes the application to assume that this new controller is part of the navigation hierarchy. What is probably the best solution is to start your application on the RootViewController, and then present the navigation controller modally. When you're done with the navigation controller, have it call `dismissModalViewController` on itself.

Comment: A bit difficult to understand :(

Comment: To avoid misunderstanding I'll explain hierarchy once more.

Comment: application starts with tab bar with 4 tabs with first tab selected.

Comment: application starts with tab bar with 4 tabs with first tab selected. This is `UINavigationController` with root `StartViewController`. What should I do next? I need a Navigation Bar to move through view controllers But Tab Bar must be hidden in everyone view controller in first tab except the first one. So to change to another tab I need to go back to StartViewController and switch to another tab.

Comment: This sounds like poor application design; that's not what a tab bar controller is intended for. However, if you really, really want to have your program work like this look at iPhone Developer's comment.

Answer (score 1):

Solved using this code:

```
-(IBAction)startPressed:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"startPressed: called");

    RootViewController *vController=[[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RootViewController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *navController=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vController];
    [vController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
    [((AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).tabBarController presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
}
```

Thanks to @iPhone Developer

Answer (score 1):

```
UIViewController *nextViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NextViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

// hide UITabbarController
nextViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;

[self.navigationController pushViewController:nextViewController animated:YES];
[nextViewController release];
```